# Skipping an activity in a sequence of activities (including a facebook activity)

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am creating an android app with the Action Bar Sherlock library. My action bar has 3 tabs, one tab requires the user to login via Facebook. There are currently three activities in this login process:

Step 1 -  The user clicks on an image button (Facebook) in one of the action bar tabs, this calls a facebook login activity.

Step 2 - Facebook login activity shows the Facebook web view, stores the users details in shared preferences and then calls the final activity

Step 3 - The Final activity displays data belonging to that user and the user can logout from this activity.

Question:

Is it possible to skip an activity when going back i.e if the user is in the final step (3) when they press the back button they go back to Step 1. So basically step 2 is not in the sequence when the user has successfully logged in.

And in addition to this is it possible to skip from Step 1 - Step 3 if the user has successfully logged in?

I've thought of overriding the back button in Step 3 but I wanted to get some concrete thoughts on this as I'm still new to android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this was the situation then i would have certainly overridden onBackPressed method or you can try Hoan nguyen's solution.

If the user has successfully logged in then you can check for the access token in shared preferences(If you have stored on successful Login. You can remove the token while doing logout.) and if it is found you can redirect to step 3 else to step 2.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml just add this line to Activity2

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

Comment: "And in addition to this is it possible to skip from Step 1 - Step 3 if the user has successfully logged in?"

Comment: I do know understand your question? If going forward from step 1 to step 3, I do not know.